# Why forkJoin is returning a wrong value from my observables?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an application that is using Firebase Storage to send some image data, so I'm using this method:

```
startUpload() {
  if (typeof this.fileList !== 'undefined' && this.fileList.length > 0) {
    const observableList = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.fileList.length; i++) {
      // The storage path
      const path = this.userModel.companyCode + `/${new Date().getTime()}_${this.fileList[i].name}`;

      // Totally optional metadata
      const customMetadata = {
        app: 'My AngularFire-powered PWA!'
      };
      const fileRef = this.storage.ref(path);

      // The main task
      this.task = this.storage.upload(path, this.fileList[i], {
        customMetadata
      });

      // Progress monitoring
      this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
      this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges();

      // The file's download URL
      observableList.push(
        this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
          finalize(async () => {
            return await fileRef.getDownloadURL();
          }))
      );

      // observableList = this.task.snapshotChanges();
      // observableList.push(taskObservable);
    }
    console.log(observableList);
    forkJoin(
      observableList
    ).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

This part:

```
this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  finalize(async () => {
    return await fileRef.getDownloadURL();
  }))
```

When I'm using this function alone and using like this:

```
this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  finalize(async () => {
    this.downloadUrl = await fileRef.getDownloadURL().toPromise;
  }))
```

They return the right URL, **this.downloadUrl is a global variable that is  downloadURL: Observable;**

But I don't want to return one by one I want the 3 results, so I have an idea to use forkJoin that is like Promise.All() from promise in javascript:

```
console.log(observableList);
forkJoin(
  observableList
).subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

And I'm getting this in the console:

> (3) [UploadTaskSnapshot, UploadTaskSnapshot, UploadTaskSnapshot]

How I can get the download URL from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finalize takes a callback function of return type void. That's why it worked in your case for handling individually, but not when you tried to return something.
[finalize-rxjs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/finalize)

I think the below code should work for you

```
 startUpload() {
    if (typeof this.fileList !== "undefined" && this.fileList.length > 0) {
      const observableList = [];
      const fileRefList = [];
      this.fileList.forEach(file => {
        const path =
          this.userModel.companyCode + `/${new Date().getTime()}_${file.name}`; // Totally optional metadata
        const customMetadata = { app: "My AngularFire-powered PWA!" };
        fileRefList.push(this.storage.ref(path)); // The main task
        this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, {
          customMetadata
        }); // Progress monitoring
        this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();
        this.snapshot = this.task.snapshotChanges();
        observableList.push(this.snapshot);
      });
      console.log(observableList);
      forkJoin(observableList)
        .pipe(map(async (_, i) => await fileRefList[i].getDownloadURL()))
        .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
    }
  }
```